# Php: where's Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in this script

Tags: php

I've got

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING
```

and I think it might be somewhere in this line (it's postdata that i'm using with curl)

Is this line causing this error? How do i fix it?

Comment: How does the code before that line look like? You’re probably just missing a quote and the `_wpnonce` is not interpreted as string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end, that's the only thing wrong with that line.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah John Kugelman is right, I just tested it, PHP is fun:
It sucks cause you can't like elaborate on a given answer or comment if you did not start 
the thread, so to John, I am not stealing your show, I just tested it out, since I am currenly also learning PHP and this site rocks when it comes to problems related to PHP and other languages in general, again credit to John Kugelman.
I just tested it, that's all.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>
ParseError
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Parseerror</h1>
<?php 
$postdata2 = "_wpnonce=". $noncestr ."&_wp_http_referer=/wp-admin/wpmu-blogs

.php&blog[domain]=testdomain&blog[title]=testtitle&blog[email]=test@test.test";
echo $postdata2;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can comment when you haven't started the thread, you just need a little more reputation :)